# Control PC's keyboard over Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard-events, hid

I want to develop an app which is similar to bluetooth keyboard . I want to control the connected PC's keyboard from my app . I can make an app that can connect to the PC via bluetooth using react native or any other language, but i am not getting how do i send the command of the keystroke to the pc over bluetooth . I dont want any other software to be installed on PC . Can any one help me with this .

I have already researched a lot about this , but so far i only came with the protocol used, that  is 'HID' .

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502780/imitate-bluetooth-human-interface-device

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan It only answers whether our device is compatible with HID or not . I want to know how to implement it as an app using any framework , which runs on a hid compatible device .

Comment: Further search for the mentioned HID profile uncovered [this open source app](https://github.com/raghavk92/Kontroller) doing exactly what you want. This was mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917415/7473793)

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Thank You so much . I think this will be usefull .