# Can an Android device pretend and connect as a Bluetooth controller?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Can an Android device pretend and connect as a Bluetooth controller?
Can Android devices connect as a device to, say, a PC and act as a [gamepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamepad) or similar device?
Is it allowed and doable in code without root access?

I tried this code: *[Connect Bluetooth devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices)*. But it can not get it to pair.

Comment: Similar to: [Imitate bluetooth Human Interface Device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58502780/295004) and [How can i use the Bluetooth HID Device profile in Android Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53555092/295004)

Comment: If you read my links, you should provide more detail in your question as to what answer you are seeking (the second link has github projects to look at).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

I recommend looking at Google's [example project on Bluetooth communication BlueToothChat](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat) initially.  Based on what you've written, I think you're missing several important steps.

You need all of the following components / steps:

0. [General Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)
1. [Set up Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/setup)
2. [Set Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)
3. [Scan for other Bluetooth devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-bluetooth-devices)
4. [Query the local Bluetooth adapter for paired Bluetooth devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-bluetooth-devices#query-paired)
5. [Connect to a remote device as client or server](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices)
6. [Transfer data over Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data)

If you have access to the device your attempting work with as a controller, then you can create your own communication setup.  Define a set of parameters to write and read on both sides that emulate the functionality you're looking for.

If you do not have access to creating your own read/write setup, or you want to use standard interaction methods for the industry, then the best bet is the [Bluetooth HID Device profile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHidDevice) mentioned by @Morrison Chang.

The HID profile basically establish an industry standard of required device features, read/write formats, combinations of features equaling a controller type (ie: "this is a keyboard"), and data mappings for what read/write numbers mean on either side of the client / server connection.

From the linked comment thread, the [Kontroller project on Github](https://github.com/raghavk92/Kontroller) has source available for your peruse.

There's also a reasonable [Intro to Bluetooth HID](https://novelbits.io/bluetooth-hid-devices-an-intro/) that covers some of the topics on what Bluetooth HID is actually doing.

Finally, also recommend looking at Google's own [BluetoothHidDevice page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHidDevice).